# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. on a transformer AI

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, transformer-model

I want to make a Transformer AI Chatbot so I followed a tutorial on kerases website on how to make a porteguese to english transalator and modified it into a chatbot, and created example sequences. However, I am encountering an error.

```
import logging
import time

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

from keras_preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras_preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

import tensorflow_text

# Dowloading the dataset and putting it into a tf.data.dataset

tokenizer = Tokenizer()

input_sequences = ["Hello, I'm Dory"]
output_sequences = ["Hey"]

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(output_sequences + input_sequences)

input_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(input_sequences)
output_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(output_sequences)

input_vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
output_vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

MAX_TOKENS = output_vocab_size

input_sequences = pad_sequences(input_sequences, MAX_TOKENS)
output_sequences = pad_sequences(output_sequences, MAX_TOKENS)

input_sequences = np.asarray(input_sequences)
output_sequences = np.asarray(output_sequences)

output_sequences = tf.convert_to_tensor(output_sequences)
input_sequences = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_sequences)

print(f"Word index: {tokenizer.word_index}")
print(f"Vocab size: {input_vocab_size}")
print(input_sequences)
print(output_sequences)

def Positional_encoding(length, depth):
    depth = depth/2

    positions = np.arange(length)[:, np.newaxis]
    depths = np.arange(depth)

    angle_rates = 1 / (10000**depths)
    angle_rads = positions * angle_rates

    pos_encoding = np.concatenate(
        [np.sin(angle_rads), np.cos(angle_rads)],
        axis=-1
    )

    return tf.cast(pos_encoding, dtype=tf.float32)

class PositionalEmbedding(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model):
        super().__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model, mask_zero=True)
        self.pos_encoding = Positional_encoding(length=2048, depth=d_model)

    def compute_mask(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.embedding.compute_mask(*args, **kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        length = tf.shape(x)[1]
        x = self.embedding(x)
        x *= tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32))
        x = x + self.pos_encoding[tf.newaxis, :length, :]
        return x

embed_in = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=input_vocab_size, d_model=512)
embed_out = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=output_vocab_size, d_model=512)

out_emb = embed_out(output_sequences)
in_emb = embed_in(input_sequences)

class BaseAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.mha = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(**kwargs)
        self.layernorm = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        self.add = tf.keras.layers.Add()

class CrossAttention(BaseAttention):
    def call(self, x, context):
        attn_output, attn_scores = self.mha(
            query=x,
            key=context,
            value=context,
            return_attention_scores=True
        )

        self.last_attn_scores = attn_scores

        x = self.add([x, attn_output])
        x = self.layernorm(x)

        return x

class GlobalSelfAttention(BaseAttention):
    def call(self, x):
        attn_output = self.mha(
            query=x,
            value=x,
            key=x
        )

        x = self.add([x, attn_output])
        x = self.layernorm(x)
        return x

class CasualSelfAttention(BaseAttention):
    def call(self, x):
        attn_output = self.mha(
            query=x,
            value=x,
            key=x
        )

        x = self.add([x, attn_output])
        x = self.layernorm(x)
        return x

class FeedForward(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, d_model, dff, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(dff, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_model),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        ])

        self.add = tf.keras.layers.Add()
        self.layer_norm = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.add([x, self.seq(x)])
        x = self.layer_norm(x)
        return x

class EncoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *, d_model, num_heads, dff, dropout_rate=0.01):
        super().__init__()

        self.self_attention = GlobalSelfAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads,
            key_dim=d_model,
            dropout=dropout_rate)

        self.ffn = FeedForward(d_model, dff)

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.self_attention(x)
        x = self.ffn(x)
        return x

class Encoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *, num_layers, d_model, num_heads,
                 dff, vocab_size, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.pos_embedding = PositionalEmbedding(
            vocab_size=vocab_size, d_model=d_model
        )

        self.enc_layers = [
            EncoderLayer(d_model=d_model,
                         num_heads=num_heads,
                         dff=dff,
                         dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
            for _ in range(num_layers)]
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)

    def call(self, x):

        x = self.pos_embedding(x)

        x = self.dropout(x)

        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x = self.enc_layers[i](x)

        return x

class DecoderLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,
                 x,
                 d_model,
                 num_heads,
                 dff,
                 dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(DecoderLayer, self).__init__()

        self.casual_self_attention = CasualSelfAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads,
            key_dim=d_model,
            dropout=dropout_rate
        )

        self.cross_attention = CrossAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads,
            key_dim=d_model,
            dropout=dropout_rate
        )

        self.ffn = FeedForward(d_model, dff)

    def call(self, x, context):
        x = self.casual_self_attention(x=x)
        x = self.cross_attention(x=x, context=context)

        self.last_attn_scores = self.cross_attention.last_attn_scores

        x = self.ffn(x)
        return x

class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff, vocab_size,
                 dropout_rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.pos_embedding = PositionalEmbedding(vocab_size=vocab_size, d_model=d_model)
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.dec_layers = [
            DecoderLayer(x=d_model, d_model=d_model, num_heads=num_heads,
                         dff=dff, dropout_rate=dropout_rate)
            for _ in range(num_layers)
        ]

        self.last_attn_scores = None

    def call(self, x, context):
        x = self.pos_embedding(x)  # (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model)

        x = self.dropout(x)

        for i in range(self.num_layers):
            x = self.dec_layers[i](x, context)

        self.last_attn_scores = self.dec_layers[-1].last_attn_scores

        # The shape of x is (batch_size, target_seq_len, d_model).
        return x

class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, *, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, dff,
               input_vocab_size, target_vocab_size, dropout_rate=0.1):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = Encoder(num_layers=num_layers, d_model=d_model,
                           num_heads=num_heads, dff=dff,
                           vocab_size=input_vocab_size,
                           dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

    self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers=num_layers, d_model=d_model,
                           num_heads=num_heads, dff=dff,
                           vocab_size=target_vocab_size,
                           dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

    self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_vocab_size)


  def call(self, inputs):
    # To use a Keras model with `.fit` you must pass all your inputs in the
    # first argument.
    context, x = inputs

    context = self.encoder(context)  # (batch_size, context_len, d_model)

    x = self.decoder(x, context)  # (batch_size, target_len, d_model)

    # Final linear layer output.
    logits = self.final_layer(x)  # (batch_size, target_len, target_vocab_size)

    try:
      # Drop the keras mask, so it doesn't scale the losses/metrics.
      # b/250038731
      del logits._keras_mask
    except AttributeError:
      pass

    # Return the final output and the attention weights.
    return logits

def lookup(tokenizer, sequence):
    word_index = tokenizer.word_index
    index_word = tokenizer.index_word
    return [index_word.get(idx, "") for idx in sequence]

num_layers = 4
d_model = 128
dff = 512
num_heads = 8
dropout_rate = 0.1

input_vocab_size = input_vocab_size
target_vocab_size = output_vocab_size

transformer = Transformer(
    num_layers=num_layers,
    d_model=d_model,
    num_heads=num_heads,
    dff=dff,
    input_vocab_size=input_vocab_size,
    target_vocab_size=target_vocab_size,
    dropout_rate=dropout_rate)

output = transformer((input_sequences, output_sequences), training=False)

class CustomSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, d_model, warmup_steps=4000):
        super().__init__()

        self.d_model = d_model
        self.d_model = tf.cast(self.d_model, tf.float32)

        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps

    def __call__(self, step):
        step = tf.cast(step, dtype=tf.float32)
        arg1 = tf.math.rsqrt(step)
        arg2 = step * (self.warmup_steps ** -1.5)

        return tf.math.rsqrt(self.d_model) * tf.math.minimum(arg1, arg2)

learning_rate = CustomSchedule(d_model)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98, epsilon=1e-9)

def masked_loss(label, pred):
    mask = label != 0
    loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
        from_logits=True, reduction='none'
    )
    loss = loss_object(label, pred)

    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss.dtype)
    loss *= mask

    loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss)/tf.reduce_sum(mask)
    return loss

def masked_accuracy(label, pred):
    pred = tf.argmax(pred, axis=2)
    label = tf.cast(label, pred.dtype)
    match = label == pred

    mask = label != 0

    match = match & mask

    match = tf.cast(match, dtype=tf.float32)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.float32)

    return tf.reduce_sum(match)/tf.reduce_sum(mask)

transformer.compile(
    loss=masked_loss,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    metrics=[masked_accuracy])

transformer.fit(x=input_sequences, y=output_sequences, epochs=5)

class Chatbot(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, tokenizers, transformer):
        self.tokenizers = tokenizers
        self.transformer = transformer

    def __call__(self, sentence, max_length=MAX_TOKENS):
        assert isinstance(sentence, tf.Tensor)
        if (len(sentence.shape)) == 0:
            sentence = sentence[tf.newaxis]

        sentence = self.tokenizers.pt.tokenize(sentence).to_tensor()

        encoder_input = sentence

        # As the output language is English, initialize the output with the
        # English `[START]` token.
        start_end = self.tokenizers.en.tokenize([''])[0]
        start = start_end[0][tf.newaxis]
        end = start_end[1][tf.newaxis]

        # `tf.TensorArray` is required here (instead of a Python list), so that the
        # dynamic-loop can be traced by `tf.function`.
        output_array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int64, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
        output_array = output_array.write(0, start)

        for i in tf.range(max_length):
            output = tf.transpose(output_array.stack())
            predictions = self.transformer([encoder_input, output], training=False)

            # Select the last token from the `seq_len` dimension.
            predictions = predictions[:, -1:, :]  # Shape `(batch_size, 1, vocab_size)`.

            predicted_id = tf.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)

            # Concatenate the `predicted_id` to the output which is given to the
            # decoder as its input.
            output_array = output_array.write(i + 1, predicted_id[0])

            if predicted_id == end:
                break

        output = tf.transpose(output_array.stack())
        # The output shape is `(1, tokens)`.
        text = tokenizer.sequences_to_texts(output)[0]

        tokens = lookup(tokenizer, output)[0]

        # `tf.function` prevents us from using the attention_weights that were
        # calculated on the last iteration of the loop.
        # So, recalculate them outside the loop.
        self.transformer([encoder_input, output[:, :-1]], training=False)
        attention_weights = self.transformer.decoder.last_attn_scores

        return text, tokens, attention_weights

Chatbot = Chatbot(tokenizer, transformer)

def print_transalation(sentence, tokens, ground_truth):
    print(f'{"Input:":15s}: {sentence}')
    print(f'{"Prediction":15s}: {tokens.numpy().decode("utf-8")}')
    print(f'{"Ground truth":15s}: {ground_truth}')

class ExportChatbot(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, chatbot):
        self.chatbot = chatbot

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
    def __call__(self, sentence):
        (result,
         tokens,
         attention_weights) = self.transalator(sentence, max_length=MAX_TOKENS)

        return result

Chatbot = ExportChatbot(Chatbot)

tf.saved_model.save(Chatbot, export_dir='Chatbot')
```

I run the code and it says:

```
    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.


Call arguments received by layer 'transformer' (type Transformer):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 5), dtype=int32)
```

I have tried to turn the sequences into arrays and convert them to tensors but nothing is working

Comment: Have you find a solution yet? I am having the same problem :(